# I need to convert a .CGM file to base64 encoded content

Tags: java, string, file, base64, cgm

I have a batch of .CGM files and it needs to be base64 encoded and get the content inside it as a String. I have no idea what the input file content type is, so I will upload a snapshot of a small piece of the input file content for reference. [CgmFileSample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa8FO.png) . Please help me in coming up with a code for this!

Comment: It's simply binary data and actually, for Base64 encoding it doesn't matter what the data represents, the encoder just reads binary data and encodes it to a Base64 string.

Comment: Yes you were right it's just binary data and reads as binary data, thanks!